# Primefaces Datatable Radiobutton submitting wrong values

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, selectoneradio

I got a datatable with a custom layout selectoneradio. It doesnt submit correct values after the first row.

This is the datatable:

```
<h:form id="dataTableForm">
        <br />
        <p:dataTable id="absenceTable" var="absence" widgetVar="absenceTable"
            value="#{adminController.absenceList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
            emptyMessage="Keine Absenzen mit ausstehender Genehmigung gefunden"
            style="width:70%;margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:10px;"
            rowKey="#{absence.id}" rows="30" paginator="true"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks}" sortBy="#{absence.startDate}"
            sortOrder="descending"
            filteredValue="#{adminController.filteredAbsences}">
            <f:facet name="header">Mitarbeiterabsenzen mit ausstehender Genehmigung</f:facet>
            <p:column>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="action" value="#{absence.status}" required="false"
                layout="custom" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="PENDING" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="APPROVED" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="REJECTED" />
                <p:ajax event="valueChange" immediate="true" listener="#{adminController.checkBoxListener}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="20">
                <p:radioButton for="action" itemIndex="0" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="20">
                <p:radioButton for="action" itemIndex="1" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="20">
                <p:radioButton for="action" itemIndex="2" />
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Speichern"
                    action="#{adminController.save()}" update="absenceTable" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

The row index and absence loop variable is defined on the datatable.

Its all in the same form.

The problem is, somehow, it only works for the first row. The other rows submit "on" instead of the value. I found in the generated html that they are not provided with value-tag like the radiobuttons in the first row are:

[image: generated output]

I guess its gonna be a stupid syntax issue or something... This is what i get debugging clicking on anything but the first row:
[image: debug event listener event]

Im running on PF 5.2

Comment: Start by removing the 'generated' id's of the radiobuttons. They should get their 'index' prefixed automaticallty.. And always try to post an [mcve]. The 'looping' is not visible now

Comment: removing the ids didnt help.. i updated the question tough

Comment: And try changing `for="dataTableForm:absenceTable:#{rowIndex}:action"` to `for="action"`. JSF takes care of the indexing for you. (besides widgetId's) but that is PF, not JSF

Comment: didnt do anything. still only the first row working properly...

Comment: Still, they are improvements. And what if you replace `<p:selectOneRadio id="action" value="#{absence.status}"` by  `<p:selectOneRadio id="action" value="#{absenceList[rowIndex].status}"` (and p[lease put the columns and datatable in one code block in the normal order)

Comment: ip updated the question. ur suggestion didnt change anything tough. i get a warning that status cant be resolved to a member of absenceList now xD

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the custom layout? (maybe it is related to that)

Comment: And what PF version are you using btw? Can you also post a minimal bean so your question becomes a [mcve] and I can easily try to reproduce

Comment: i run PF5.2; removing the custom layout rendered all buttons deactivated xD

Comment: Deactivated? That is weird... Did you just remove the custom layout attribute or also all of the radiobuttons? Can you try 5.3/6.0/6.1 to see if all these have the same problem (both the deactivation and original problem) (try the latest, 6.1, first if possible)

Comment: no im stuck with this version; i couldnt just update even if it worked; and trying to change the version results in a lot of errors. cant even start the application like this

Comment: TRY... just for this issue... Just with an [mcve]... If it is impossible to even check if a newer version has the same issue or not, I think support stops here for me, sorry. I don't have the time doing that for you for you, I hope you understand that. Good luck finding a solution...

Comment: i did try, as i said it didnt work, couldnt get the page to load. and im stuck to this version still. anyway thx

Comment: I you had an [mcve] you most likely did not get a lot of errors, maybe just one or two and most likely easily to circumvent... That is one of the additional reasons for creating an [mcve]...

Comment: A simple version, `<p:dataTable id="absenceTable" var="absence" value="#{adminController.absenceList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">` with the columns like you have works for me on PF 6.1... (not tested on 5.2 since my personal showcase does not run on that version anymore). So the problem is either in the version you use or in not visible code or in the additional attributes on the datatable. This is all info I can provide... cheers.

Comment: i was having problems with the nexus server the other day, thats why i couldnt try it out

now that the nexus is running again, i was able to verify that indeed this is a bug in PF5.2

it runs smooth with PF5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in PF5.2

The code runs smoothly on PF5.3

Comment: Great it works, next time if you encounter issues, **always**  create a [mcve] and always try a newer version.